# Calculus I help - any useful resources, for seemingly "Advanced Calc I"

Tags: calculus, advice

Disclaimer: I am not looking for anyone to provide in depth solutions (or any solutions for that matter) to any of the questions. The sample worksheets have just been posted to give an idea of what standards I am talking about. I would like resources where this work can be learnt, because my university is not willing to help their students in this regard.

I watched Professor Leonard's videos and he helped a lot, but it seems like the level of work he teaches is somehow nowhere near the level of my Calculus I course, which makes no sense. It's almost as though they've taken the Calculus I course of the textbook(amazon.com/Calculus-James-Stewart/dp/1285740629), but then added much deeper content to it.

I have attached a sample of our questions below. If anyone could advise me on where I can find resources to help me, that would really and truly be appreciated!

Thank you

Our course information: https://www.up.ac.za/yearbooks/2020/modules/view/WTW%20114

Our study guide: https://1drv.ms/b/s!Aum4yyXWXkX3gesY5D6WRcQZOnUnXg

Samples of our worksheets: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aum4yyXWXkX3goBMIO411IGhUzue5g?e=lfCzFO

Comment: Try to  solve every problem step by step. If you have a specific question, you can post it in here.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It's just often a matter of there being questions that I don't even know where to start, because the content isn't covered in the lecture or the textbook. I have done the majority of these questions, so I'll scan my answers and add it to the OneDrive link. My main concern is not the answers themselves though. It's more a matter of finding out if anyone else has done this sort of work in Calculus I. If they have, I'd like to know if they have any resources. Because Calc I resources are abundant online, but none of them that I've found are this rigorous

Comment: I find the statement "It's almost as though they've taken the Calculus I course, but then added stuff to it" odd, in the sense that there is no "universal" calc I course that students take worldwide. For this reason, learning via videos on the internet can give you a false impression of your own level compared to other students at your university, and will not prepare you for the exams you will face.

Comment: My comment stems not from the universal standpoint, but rather the textbook standpoint. They've given us a textbook (https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-James-Stewart/dp/1285740629), but only 40-50% of the content seems to be covered in this textbook. The rest of it they seemingly just want us to shoot in the dark

Comment: I agree with @vitamind. You should present an explicit problem or question.

Comment: That is some good mathematics that you’re being taught.

Answer (score 2):

The study guide seems to be pretty thorough.  For instance, the notes for the section on absolute value talk about the important applications of the function, some tips for reasoning with it, and strong advice to commit the proof of the triangle inequality to memory.  As an instructor, I think that's more than enough bridge material between the text and the problem set (especially some of the absolute value problems you highlighted).

I noticed you remarked on the problem set that you can solve some of the problems, but you're worried about the time it takes to solve them, especially since exams are timed.  University instructors are probably not going to be focused on the skill of solving routine problems quickly, and maybe that's leading to your impression that the university "is not willing to help students."

If you want to be able to solve calculus problems quickly, focus first on solving them at all—speed will come with experience and practice.

Answer (score 0):

Well after hours of searching, I finally found a helpful source.

Again, this is not intended to be a solution provider, but rather a content provider. For anyone who finds themselves doing a similar course to me, check out the following link :https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-006-calculus-revisited-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/study-materials/

It solves 90-95% of my problems!